# OOM Exception trying to create a simple calendar interface

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I've been trying to create a simple calendar interface using a table, but I keep getting pesky "out of memory" exceptions....am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Just for a note, the `TimePeriod1` and `TimePeriod2` are just the days of the month split up, ie, day 1-15 and day 16-29.

```
        <tbody>
            <% int days = Model.TimePeriod1.Count + Model.TimePeriod2.Count;
               int day = 1;
               while (day < days) { %>
                    <tr>
                    <% while ((day % 7) != 0){ %>
                        <td><%: day++ %></td>
                    <% } %>
                    </tr>
               <% } %>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `day` reaches the number 7, it will break the inner while and go back to the second one. If  `days` is greater than 7, it will continue to loop but will neved enter the inner while again, that's why you are getting a OOM exception.

One possible solution is to add `day++` before the end of the first while:

```
<% 
int days = Model.TimePeriod1.Count + Model.TimePeriod2.Count;
int day = 1;
while (day < days) { %>
    <tr>
    <% while ((day % 7) != 0){ %>
        <td><%: day++ %></td>
    <% } %>
    </tr>
    <% day++; %>
<% } %>
```